# Change CPanel password via SSH

Tags: ssh, cpanel, putty

I lost my CPanel user & password. I have direct access to server (SSH). Can I change my CPanel user & pass over SSH? (with Putty). If this possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have root access to server or is it shared hosting?

- If you have root access to server

You can reset the Cpanel password by logging in to WHM. Access IPaddress-of-server:2087 and this will redirect you to the WHM page and you can login using the root password and in 'Account functions >> Password modification' you can reset the Cpanel password.

- If you have only user access to server

Login to the server using SSH and type 'passwd' and Enter the current SSH password you have and enter the New-password you want. This will reset both the SSH and Cpanel password to the same.

Answer (score 0):

As a normal user from jailshell I don't it's possible possible to reset your password...as for knowing the user - it's the same as the user you use for logging in to ssh.